# MVC 4 @HTML.HiddenFor are not updating on a postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Having issues with the view state on a series of page views -- On the initial view of a page in Razor I am using `Html.HiddenFor` as follows:

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.err)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.errField)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.errMessage)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.IsMove)
```

which seems to work fine. My hidden input tags contain the correct values.  However when I submit the form `[HTTPPost]` and update the model in my controller action with..

```
       model.err = transHelper.err;
       model.errField = transHelper.errField;
       model.errMessage = transHelper.errMessage;
       return View(model);
```

The hidden fields do not seem to update, they contain the original values from the initial view.  However When I use these fields in another context within the same razor view like this...

```
     @*      
        this seems to not update correctly...

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.err)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.errField)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.errMessage)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.IsMove)

        *@
        <input type="hidden" id="err" value="@Model.err" />
        <input type="hidden" id="errField" value="@Model.errField" />
        <input type="hidden" id="errMessage" value="@Model.errMessage" />
        <input type="hidden" id="IsMove" value="@Model.IsMove" />

    </div>
```

Then the input fields update correctly.  I even created a View Helper to help debug, and in all cases, the Model seems to have correct data in  `HtmlHelper<TModel>` -- I even returned the Model as `return Json(model);` and the data was fine.

At this point I am running with the work around, but does anybody know why `@Html.HiddenFor` is dirty.

Update:  here is my controller actions

```
  [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Index(HomePageModel model)
   {


       // process transaction
       Transactionr transr = new Transactionr();
       transr.Process(model);

       model.err = transr.err;
       model.errField = transr.errField;
       model.errMessage = transr.errMessage;

       return View(model);
   }
```

Here is my view:

```
        @model App.Models.HomePageModel
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Product Categorizer";
    }
    <form id="formData" method="post" action="/Home/Index">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <fieldset>
            <div>

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.err)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.errField)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.errMessage)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IsMove)

            <input type="hidden" id="myerr" value="@Model.err" />
            <input type="hidden" id="myerrField" value="@Model.errField" />

            </div>

           <div class="section group">
                <div class="col span_2_of_2">
                     <div class="message" id ="message">
                         @if (Model.err < 0)
                         {
                             <span style="color: purple;">@Model.errMessage (@Model.err) - (@Model.errField)</span>
                         }
                         else if (Model.err > 0)
                         {
                             <span style="color:red;">@Model.errMessage (@Model.err) (@Model.errField)</span>
                         } else {
                            <span>@Model.errMessage (@Model.err) (@Model.errField)</span>
                         }
                         </div>
                     </div>
            </div>

            <div class="section group" id="workspace">
                  @Html.Partial("_WorkspacePartial", Model)
            </div>
              <div class="section group" id="details">
                  @Html.Partial("_DetailPartial", Model)
              </div>


        </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Here is my model:

```
 public class HomePageModel
 {
    public int FromStore { get; set; }

    //  the "To" part of the copy/move transaction
    public int ToStore { get; set; }

    // a list of the copy/move transaction
    public List<int> Details { get; set; }


    // true is move false is copy
    public bool IsMove { get; set; }

    // current message
    public int err { get; set; }
    public int errField { get; set; }
    public string errMessage { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 39):

The default HtmlHelpers behavior (@Html.HiddenFor, etc) is to behave exactly as you have described.

i.e. any changes you make to the ViewModel on a post are actioned, any changes you return from the Post are received by the view, but on re-rendering WITH HTMLHELPERS, the previous Post-values take precedence over the changed ViewModel values.

Want to "fix" this behavior in a quick + dirty way, clear the ModelState.Clear() prior to returning from the HttpPost ActionMethod !

Comment: This is very dirty because all the Validation messages are cleared then as well, so be aware!

Comment: I thought I was going crazy.

Comment: I don't get it.  There's no Required attribute on any properties of the model.  Why returning the view was getting the HiddenFor empty for ONE property ?  After doing the ModelState.Clear I was getting the value all right !!!

Comment: ***WHY*** _ clear the ModelState.Clear() prior to returning from the HttpPost ActionMethod_ ?

Comment: Odd behavior (still persists in Razor Pages). It seems to occur because `By default, the validation system treats non-nullable parameters or properties as if they had a [Required] attribute.` according to the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.0#required-attribute), but even a single `string` type (nullable) model property used as hidden-input (via `asp-for`) is affected by this behavior, and its value is silently reverted to the previous value.

Answer (score 14):

As mentioned by joedotnot this is intended behaviour. Another 'quick fix' for this is to code the html for the hidden field and update only the value from the model eg:

```html
<input type="hidden" id="ErrMessage" name="ErrMessage" value="@Model.ErrMessage">
```

Use the same `id` and `name` as your model property and the updated value will be rendered after postback.

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I've faced similar problem recently and ended up with writing new simple helper method + 2 overloads. I'm sharing it here in case anybody is still looking for some workaround cause this "feature" is sometimes annoying.

```
public static class CustomExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString HiddenFor2<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        ReplacePropertyState(htmlHelper, expression);
        return htmlHelper.HiddenFor(expression);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString HiddenFor2<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        ReplacePropertyState(htmlHelper, expression);
        return htmlHelper.HiddenFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString HiddenFor2<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes)
    {
        ReplacePropertyState(htmlHelper, expression);
        return htmlHelper.HiddenFor(expression, htmlAttributes);
    }

    private static void ReplacePropertyState<TModel, TProperty>(HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
    {
        string text = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
        string fullName = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(text);
        ModelStateDictionary modelState = htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState;

        if (modelState.ContainsKey(fullName))
        {
            ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
            ValueProviderResult currentValue = modelState[fullName].Value;
            modelState[fullName].Value = new ValueProviderResult(metadata.Model, Convert.ToString(metadata.Model), currentValue.Culture);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just use it as usual from within you view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor2(m => m.Id)
```

It worth to mention it works with collections too.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should be using them like this instead:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Err)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ErrField)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ErrMessage)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IsMove)
```

Without seeing your model, I am assuming it looks something like this:

```
public class ErroViewModel
{
  public string Err { get; set; }
  public string ErrField { get; set; }
  public string ErrMessage { get; set; }
  public bool IsMove { get; set; }
}
```

If not it should be similar with public properties as above.

**Update**

In your get do you have the following?

```
public ActionResult Index(HomePageModel model)
{
   var model = new HomePageModel();
   return View(model);
}
```

I would also change your form from this:

```
 <form id="formData" method="post" action="/Home/Index">
```

To this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
  // rest of form
}
```

Comment: My Model is using public properties.  In terms of the expression, I've tried everything including what you suggest, and it doesn't seem to have any impact.

Comment: Yes, in my get am creating an instance of HomePageModel.. as for the form.. I am doing some form manipulation with jquery so I've coded it like that.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what the problem could be as it all looks good for me. Still an issue?

Comment: Its the `ModelState` that is causing it. See the other answer.

Comment: Why not use `[HttpPost]` ***attribute*** ?

Comment: @Kiquenet I would yes, it was just missing from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it like this.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { onclick = "this.select()", Value = Model.Email, Placeholder = "E-Mail" })
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a key in your view model. If you don't have any property named as Id in your view model, set one of them (expected to be uniqe identifiyer) as key with [Key].

```
[Key]
Myproperty {get;set;}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
<input type="hidden" id="SomeFieldID" name="SomeFieldID" value="@Model.SomeFieldID" />
```

Comment: This looks like it was already covered it [maxscan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26034919/1366033) posted two years earlier