# Getting Null value while Passing Model Property to a function in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an array inside javascript for storing all field values and am passing that array to a model property `AddChecklistSurveyResult`. After submitting the page am trying to pass this model property as a parameter inside a function `SaveLpgResult` while calling service, It's showing Null, Thanks in advance.

## MODEL (QAGInspectionViewModel )

```
public string AddChecklistSurveyResult { get; set; }
```

## HTML

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

 <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddChecklistSurveyResult);
}
```

## JAVASCRIPT

```
 function LpgChecklist() 
{
  $.each(answers, function (index, value) {
                surveyIdList = surveyIdObj
                surveyTemplateList = surveyTemplateObj
                answerList = value.answerListId;
                question = value.questionId;
                value = value.value;
                ChecklistDetails.push({
                    answerArr: answerList,
                    QuestionArr: question,
                    valueArr: value
                });

                console.log(ChecklistDetails);

                $("#AddChecklistSurveyResult").val(JSON.stringify(ChecklistDetails));

            });
```

## CONTROLLER

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult _QAGInspectionDetails(QAGInspectionViewModel model)
{
    var save = qAGCaseService.Create(model);
}
```

## qAGCaseService (SERVICE)

```
public bool Create(QAGInspectionViewModel model)
{
    SaveLpgResult(model.AddChecklistSurveyResult, model.EntryBy);
    //Here Am getting Null for model.AddChecklistSurveyResult
}
```

Am Expecting  result like this:

```
[
  {
    "LPG_Brand":"Caltex",
    "LPG_Status":null,
    "LPG_Capacity":"13.3",
    "LPG_Used":"",
    "LPG_Unused":"",
    "LPG_Quantity":"",
    "LPG_Detained":"Yes",
    "LPG_StorageLocation":"EMSD",
    "LPG_Brand_Display":null,
    "LPG_Capacity_Display":null,
    "LPG_Detained_Display":null,
    "LPG_StorageLocation_Display":null
   }
 ]
```

Comment: When I did Console.log(  $("#AddChecklistSurveyResult").val(JSON.stringify(ChecklistDetails))) I got result as _jQuery.fn.init [input#AddLPGCylinderDetails]_

Comment: Firstly, since you are using `$each` can you take `$("#AddChecklistSurveyResult").val(JSON.stringify(ChecklistDetails));` out of the `$each` block?, then before the line where you will have it, do a `Console.log(ChecklistDetails)`, also show how you are submitting the page

Comment: I did Console.log(ChecklistDetails), Am getting data like this:  _[{…}]
0: {answerArr: "1", QuestionArr: "3", valueArr: "OVEN"}_

Comment: I had given <button type="submit"> for form submittion

Comment: can you post html code from <form></form> tag or from @html.beginform

Comment: plus can you post generated hidden field from source of page

Comment: Take a look at those answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757343/mvc-hidden-field-via-html-helper-in-form-post-issue or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657706/mvc-4-html-hiddenfor-are-not-updating-on-a-postback

Comment: I had found the problem when I submit the form the hiddenField value becomes null. when I put to check the hidden field value inside a javascript function, I am getting value. Gone through the document mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solve the problem. Added an onclick event inside the button for calling the javascript function

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" onclick="LpgChecklist()">Save</button>
```