# Form Binding with MVC and Reading Values from Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I have implemented a simple form in MVC with Razor syntax.

```
@model QuisenberryMVC001.Models.ConsoleCommand    

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Product</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.input)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.input)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.output)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.output)
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Run" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

The model:

```
public class ConsoleCommand
    {
        public String input {get; set;}
        public String output { get; set;}
    }
```

This form displays a text box to accept input and a text area to display output. I have implemented a controller to prepare the output. Ultimately, this will be done by the model.

Here is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyConsole(ConsoleCommand command)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "My Console";
    command.output += "My Output";
    return View(command);
}
```

I would like for clicking the "Run" button to update the text area with the text "My Output". Instead, it displays whatever value the user typed.

When I debug the application, I see that `command.output` actually is "My Output" when `return View(command)` is reached. I am unable to see what value the view receives, as putting a watch on `model` or `model.output` results in an error like `The name 'model' does not exist in the current context`.

It looks the values are ready correctly from the form but not written correctly to the form. How do I fix binding?

Comment: Use `ModelState.Clear()` -- see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838335/mvc-model-not-updating

Comment: @stephen.vakil, Thank you. Adding that method to my HttpPost method resolved the issue.