# View takes values from query string instead of model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, razorengine

I have an action in my controller:

```
public PartialViewResult MyAction(int? myId, int? myId2)
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel() { MyId = 10, MyId2 = 20 }
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

Here is my view:

```
@model StartSite.Models.Shared.MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyId2)

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submin" />
    </p>
}
```

Lets call MyAction with params **myId=1&myId2=2**. But the model is created with different values **new MyModel() { MyId = 10, MyId2 = 20 }**. And what should be rendered in view? As I expect it should be:

```
<input id="MyId" name="MyId" type="hidden" value="10">
<input id="MyId2" name="MyId2" type="hidden" value="20">
```

But in fact the result is:

```
<input id="MyId" name="MyId" type="hidden" value="1">
<input id="MyId2" name="MyId2" type="hidden" value="2">
```

As I guess the **Html.HiddenFor** takes values not from my model but from **Reauest.QueryString** which is **myId=1&myId2=2** at the moment the view is rendered.

Why it happens? Is it expected behaviour?

**UPDATE 1:**
I've edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: Where's `myId2` coming from? That a copy-paste error, or we looking at a property of your controller? (it's exempt from action signature)

Comment: Yes, sorry for this typo. It's correct now.

Comment: make a return view instead of return partial view and let me know if you still face this error. If not I can explain you the detail.

Comment: I tried, it didn't help. I think that html-helper logic is the same for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

to have access to the Model in the submit try with this

```
   [HttpPost]
   public virtual PartialViewResult MyAction(MyModel  model)
   {
     //MyModel model = new MyModel();

     // if (myId != null)
     //    model.MyId= myId;
     // else if (myId2 != null)
     //   model.MyId2= myId2;

    //now you have access to your model values
    return PartialView(model);
 }
```

Comment: check this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837744/hiddenfor-not-getting-correct-value-from-view-model

Comment: I understand the idea for post cases, but don't understand why it works this way in my case with get-action. I define value in model but the view takes them from query string. Anyway thank you for pointing the way to fix it.

Comment: I mean ModelState, not query string.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior. Firstly, an `Action` without any Attributes is automatically a `HttpGet`. Next, your `Action` expects a value for '`myId`'. This means, if the url calling your `Action` has a querystring that matches, it'll accept the value. Finally, the value your `Action` accepts is case-**insensitive**. Therefore, you do not need to manually set your model values. You can simply do this:

```
public virtual PartialViewResult MyAction(MyModel model)
{
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

So when you go to your url, e.g. `localhost/myaction?myId=2`, `model.MyId` will be set to 2.

If you do NOT want your model set by a querystring, you must change your `Action` to not accept any values.

Comment: Let's not talk about post-action. My question is about @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MyId2) in the view, which renders myId2 from request values, not from model.

Comment: This is how it works. GET is a 'post-action' just as much as POST is. If you pass in a querystring with matching values, it's automatically a GET. To get around this, you need to create another action. One that doesnt accept a querystring, and one for your "post-action".